# Process many texts with Stanford parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to process many snippets of text using the stanford parser. I am outputing to xml using this command

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-VV.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse -file test
```

all i need is the sentence parse of each of the snippets. The problem is that the snippets can have more than one sentence, and the output xml gives all the sentences together, so i cant know which sentences belong to what snippet. I could add a separator word between different sentences, but i think there must be a built in capability to show separation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter -fileList that takes a string of comma-separated files as its input.

Example:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-VV.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse -fileList=file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt
```

Have a look at the SentimentPipeline.java (edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment) for further details.